# Sharing Angular Components in single-spa micro frontends

Tags: angular, webpack, single-spa, single-spa-angular

I am building an application on micro frontend architecture using single-spa. All we want is to have a micro frontend with all the reusable components and share it across others.
Is there a way I can export the components from one angular application and use in another while using single-spa ?

I have tried the given examples from single spa documentation but it didn't help me much. Used the below link for reference.

https://single-spa.js.org/docs/recommended-setup#cross-microfrontend-imports

Comment: just use nx and thats all  i would recommend.

Comment: Hi, do you have any updates about this issue? Thank you in advance